# Abstract noun for solecism

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, malapropisms, abstract-nouns

I am looking for the abstract, non-count form of solecism, if it exists. Just as "brevity" describes the *quality* of being brief, I am looking for an abstract noun to denote the quality of being incorrect, such as "incorrectness", but geared towards speech. Is solecity/solecisity a word, or is it, itself, a solecism?

If none exists, perhaps there is one for malapropism?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Although both *solecism* and *malapropism* may be more common as count nouns, they can themselves both be used as mass or abstract nouns too. OED lists some non-count or “without article” senses of *solecism* as Rare, but conspicuously not the one in question here. Under *malapropism* the sole definition given offers a non-count sense first, and the count sense after a semicolon:

> The ludicrous misuse of words, esp. in mistaking a word for another resembling it; an instance of this.

Comment: Very good information here. So you are saying that both words can be used in the non-count (mass) sense as well? Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it might be ***impropriety***:

> - An improper or unacceptable usage in speech or writing.
> - The quality or condition of being improper.
>
> [[thefreedictionary]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impropriety)

A definition of *solecism* from [University of Hull](http://slb-ltsu.hull.ac.uk/awe/index.php?title=Solecism):

> It is a sign of the perceived importance of ‘correct’ language that the original meaning was “An **impropriety or irregularity** in speech or diction; a violation of the rules of grammar or syntax; properly, a faulty concord.”

Though as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solecism) says:

> What is considered a solecism in one register of a language might be acceptable usage in another.

Answer (score 1):

Also see *[Word or phrase for clumsy, inaccurate expression](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/45474)*, where terms like the following are suggested:

• *[infelicity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/infelicity)*, “A thing that is inappropriate, especially a remark or expression: ‘*she winced at their infelicities and at the clumsy way they talked*’” – oxforddictionaries.com
• *[clumsiness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clumsiness)*, “A lack of coordination or elegance; the condition or quality of being clumsy” (wiktionary) and various synonyms like  *blundering, crude, gauche, ill-shaped, inept*, et al
• *[incoherent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incoherent#Adjective)*, “Lacking coherence or agreement; incongruous; inconsistent; not logically connected” – wiktionary
• *[botched](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/botched#Adjective)*, “clumsily made or repaired in an unacceptable or incompetent manner”, applied figuratively; and also consider *botchiness* in less formal communications